# How to select data with some of between in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-server-2008-r2, between

In case I have two table. One is the sales table and the other is event table.

the sales table:

```
Date        Item   Qty
2014-10-01     A     2
2014-10-01     B     3
2014-10-05     A     5
2014-10-10     A     2
2014-10-11     A     2
2014-10-19     A     3
2014-10-19     B     6
2014-10-25     A     2
2014-10-25     B     1
2014-10-30     B     4
```

and the event table:

```
Event       Begin_Date     End_Date
Holiday     2014-10-01     2014-10-03
Holiday     2014-10-10     2014-10-13
Month Sale  2014-10-29     2014-10-30
```

How can select only the sales in event period?

In example, holiday event the result would be like this:

```
Date        Item   Qty
2014-10-01     A     2
2014-10-01     B     3
2014-10-10     A     2
2014-10-11     A     2
```

Comment: Does the sales table have a primary key? If so, what is it?

Comment: The primary key of sales table is the date and the item.

Comment: Why `2014-10-05` not there in the result?

Comment: @Ullas Because that date isn't in any of the holiday ranges!

Answer (score 0):

Join on the dates

```
SELECT S.*
FROM Event E
JOIN Sales S on S.Date Between E.Begin_Date and E.End_Date
where E.Event='Holiday'
```

--Edit
If you have overlapping events the you would have to use the distinct keyword as such:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.*
FROM Event E
JOIN Sales S on S.Date Between E.Begin_Date and E.End_Date
where E.Event='Holiday'
```

Comment: If you have overlapping events then this would return multiple results for overlapping events, but a simple distinct would take care of that see edit

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by someone few mins back was removed by himself. i checked on the same it is working.
(same answer except distinct keyword)

```
  SELECT a.*
    FROM   #sales a
           JOIN #event b
             ON a.mydate BETWEEN b.begin_date AND b.end_date
    WHERE  b.event = 'Holiday'
```

Comment: The distinct keyword is important to cope with overlapping events

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM SALES 
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN 
                   (SELECT BEGIN_DATE FROM EVENT) 
               AND 
                   (SELECT END_DATE FROM EVENT))
AND EVENT.EVENT = 'HOLIDAY'
```